# Is clinging the reason for losing interest towards certain things?

Tags: desire

We lose interest to certain things (foods, vehicles .. etc.) with time. Is clinging the reason for this ? Is this the nature of clinging ?

Are we able to maintain the interest level if we don't have clinging ? Does losing interest to do something (working on a project, studying, new year resolutions, etc.) means that I had the clinging to that thing (or end result) initially ?

Comment: Are you asking, "Why am I unable to concentrate on doing something e. g. studying? Is it because my mind get distracted as a result of, being attached to other things?" But you also ask about food and vehicles so I don't understand the question. Why would lack of interest be caused by clinging?

Comment: This is something similar to motivation for studying, reason for the losing motivation. I guess , clinging is the reason, because desire decreases and some other desires build up. So, I got a example to describe it . Thanks :) .

Answer (score 2):

> We lose interest to certain things (foods, vehicles .. etc.) with time. Is clinging the reason for this ? Is this the nature of clinging ?

No, this is due to the impermanence of things (anicca).

> Are we able to maintain the interest level if we don't have clinging ? Does losing interest to do something (working on a project, studying, new year resolutions, etc.) means that I had the clinging to that thing (or end result) initially ?

It's the other way around. Interest in working, studying or new year resolutions are different forms of clinging, or grasping for that matter.

To clarify, the point here is not to be indifferent, but rather to foster equanimity.

Answer (score -1):

This is a good question. When we age our interest changes to different things. When we are young we like toy cars and when we are adults we like real cars. When we get old and not able to move we think about the death and the afterlife. Sexual desire diminish and take sports or consume food. Some times we develop aversion instead of clinging.
Practicing Vipassana meditation and practicing Brahma vihara is the way to keep you still interested in working and studying etc.
There is a hierarchy of how interest keeps on changing. Which is called Ten Mara.
https://dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=35806&p=549952&hilit=